# Convert Windows commandline output from Cp1252 to comparable String

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm executing a Windows command and need to parse the results output, and compare part of the text with a string previously stored in java code.

But apparently the charset mismatch prevents the equals to return true.

Thats my code:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
    pb.command("systeminfo");
    Process shell = pb.start();
    InputStream shellIn = shell.getInputStream();


    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(shellIn, "Cp1252");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

    String sCurrentLine;
    while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

        // ... omitting parse of sCurrentLine for brevity
        System.out.println("DOS String:" + sCurrentLine);
        System.out.println("JAVA String: "+ Versão");
        System.out.println("Versão".equals(sCurrentLine));
    }
```

And my output will be: (Commandline window):

```
    Windows String: Versão
    JAVA String: VersÒo
    false
```

To a text file:

```
    Windows String: VersÒo
    JAVA String: Versão
    false
```

I've found a couple of similar issues here in stackoverflow but none of the anwsers worked for me.

[converting String from Windows charset to UTF 8 in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436188/converting-string-from-windows-charset-to-utf-8-in-java)

[Converting from Windows 1252 to UTF8 in Java: null characters with CharsetDecoder/Encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127528/converting-from-windows-1252-to-utf8-in-java-null-characters-with-charsetdecode)

[How to parse a string that is in a different encoding from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016671/how-to-parse-a-string-that-is-in-a-different-encoding-from-java)

[Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)

[How to Find the Default Charset/Encoding in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-default-charset-encoding-in-java)

Comment: How is your Java source code file coded? UTF8? Windows Ansi/CP1252?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using, you can use `chcp` to show the codepage that a console window is using, And that is not something like 1252,  but 850 (an old DOS code page) on my computer. Maybe you should use that in your `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: @Holger, this error is due other user edition, anyway, this details doesn't matter.

Comment: @FrankPl this solved the issue. Thanks a lot ! Now, how do we 'convert' a comment in a answer ?

Comment: I added the content as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line in most cases does not use a standard Windows code page, but an old DOS one. According to [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using), you can find out which using the command `chcp` on the command line to find out which it uses in your environment. On my computer, this command shows `850`. Thus, I would assume this is the codepage which is used, and hence you should use that in your call to `new InputStreamReader`.

I am not sure, however, if this applies to all versions of Windows in all locales. Actually, I never used a Japanese, Arabic, Chinese, or Korean Windows.